# can we use the jquery one() for attribute class having multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

What I am trying to do is, I have different `DIV` element having different `ID`'s and same `class`

What I know is:

```
 $(id).one()
```

and

```
 $(class).one()
```

it work as given in the doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/) : Attach a handler to an event for the elements.
     The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

What I want:

```
 $(class).one()
```

The handler is executed at most once per `ID` i.e  once per DIV element per event type.
and not only once for a class?

Solution I know:

```
$(id1).one()

$(id2).one()

$(id3).one() ...
```

write it as many time as ID's I have which `I don't want`

is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once per ID? IDs are unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what are you asking for . but `most once per element per event type`
class selector should work

```
 <div class="click">click1</div>
<div class="click">click2</div>

 $('.click').one("click",function(){
       alert('clicked');
 })
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/YSHy6/)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, that you want the click to trigger once per class, the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function with `selector` parameter should do the trick:

```
$(document).one("click", ".div-group", function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/a4XbL/)

Comment: No, What I want is (in DEMO)the above alert to display on each div but exactly once, if you click on any div second time alert will not displayed

Comment: Then I do not see what problem you are facing; `.one` should work as-is (see bipen's  answer).

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you want to add a `one()` to all element of that class, but each of those items may only be clicked once:

```
<div class="click">click1</div>
<div class="click">click2</div>

$('.click').one("click",function(){
    $(this).off('click'); // torn off click event
    alert( 'This element will not alert this message again' );
})
```

Comment: you don't need `off` there at all.. check out `.one()` in jquery docs... `one()` was introduce for exact same reason so that you don't have to call `on()` and `off()` function again and again

Comment: So it binds the event to each matching element, so 3 elements mean I can trigger it 3 times?